# Does the leader of a group action roll themselves?

Tags: scum-and-villainy, forged-in-the-dark

When leading a group action, do you roll the action yourself, or do you just take the stress penalties from other people's failed rolls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When you lead a **group action**, you coordinate multiple members of the team to tackle a problem together. Describe how your character leads the team in a coordinated effort. …
>
> Each PC who's involved makes an **action roll** (using the same action) and the team counts **the single best result** as the overall effort for everyone who rolled. (Page 158.)

Leading the group action certainly involves you, so you roll as well.

Comment: Blades in the Dark makes this crystal clear by including a group action in the example of play, but I didn't see such an example in Scum and Villainy.